# How to fetch the primary key value of a recently inserted row

Tags: python, mysql

```
import MySQLdb
```

How to fetch the primary key value of a recently inserted row, in the following execution.

```
cursor = mysql.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO foos (val1,val2) VALUES (%s,%s)""", (v1, v2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

> Cursor.lastrowid
>
> This read-only attribute provides the rowid of the last modified row (most databases return a rowid only when a single INSERT operation is performed).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a a timestamp on your table and fetch using `now() - interval 1 hour` for example

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio's answer is more appropriate for the API you're using but in general.

MySQL allows you to get the ID of the most recent insert.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```